# C++ std::map with value type std::map

Tags: c++, templates, dictionary, stl

How would the following code be written correctly?

```
map< int, map< double, bool > > mymap;
mymap.insert( map< int, map< double, bool > >::value_type(50, map< double, bool >::value_type(0.1, false) ) );
```

Comment: It's generally discouraged to use a `double` as a key for a `map`; sometimes it's hard to get two double values to be exactly equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about this:

```
typedef map<double, bool> innerType;
map<int, innerType> outer;
innerType inner;
inner.insert(pair<double, bool>(1.0, false));
outer.insert(pair<int, innerType>(1, inner));
```

Answer (score 2):

If C++11 is available to you (and your spacing indicates it is not):

```
mymap.insert({50, {{0.1,false}}});
```

Without C++11, `typedef` is your friend, and see navono's answer.  Personally, I would just use this:

```
mymap[50][0.1] = false;
```

Comment: I think you need one more closing brace `}`, however do you know why you need to double up the braces, i.e. `{50, {{0.1,false}}}` works but `{50, {0.1,false}}` doesn't?

Comment: @JesseGood: Because `map<double, bool>` doesn't have a constructor which takes a `double` and a `bool`, which `{0.1, false}` would serve to provide. It does, however, have a constructor which takes an initialization list of `std::pair<const double, bool>`.  And that's what `{{0.1, false}}` serves as, an initialization list consisting of a single pair.

Comment: great answer! but sadly, I can't make the program C++11 compliant yet